# Vuetify v-treeview, how to show the content of nodes without children?

Tags: vuejs2, treeview, vuetify.js

The Vuetify site has this nice example of a [dynamic load tree](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/treeview/#load-children). If you click in a leaf node (a node without children) it shows its content. Using the `v-on:update:active` event, it is easy to know when these nodes are selected. I would like to also show the content of nodes that have children. However, clicking on these nodes opens or closes them. I would like to show their content when I click on their text, and open/close them when I click on their open/close icons. How can I do it?

Remember that I need the `id` of a node to access its contents. I am using Vue2.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to delete the attribute `open-on-click`.

In the documentation, it states that: *When using this prop with activatable you will be unable to mark nodes with children as active.*

But I did not have any problem using `:active.sync="active"` (`this.active` is a component field) to get the active nodes.